# Can not Load Image in HTML from bundle

Tags: html, iphone, xcode, uiwebview

Hello all i am posting 2 images of HTML.One is HTML which i get from DATABASE and other is in which i have tried to replace the path to show html with image in web but i can not load image please help me....

### 1)BEFORE

### [image]

after applying this code

```
NSString *html = [[arr objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Text"];
             NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Help05" ofType:@".png"];

    NSString *fixedURL = [path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"",fixedURL];
                html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ImagePath" withString:str];

2) AFTER

[image]

Comment: Looks like the image may not be in the same directory in which the Html page is present. You may try something like ../images/

Comment: @Nirmal html will come from database dynamically

Comment: But the png image should be there somewhere in the directory. Right ? Also the image has no closing tag.

Comment: @Nirmal yes but still cant get

Comment: Shouldn't you replace "@"imagePath""? Your AFTER-code also shows double "